# Battleships SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

Here is a schema about battleships and the battles they fought in:

```
 Ships(name, yearLaunched, country, numGuns, gunSize, displacement)
 Battles(ship, battleName, result)
```

A typical Ships tuple would be:

```
 ('New Jersey', 1943, 'USA', 9, 16, 46000)
```

which means that the battleship New Jersey was launched in 1943; it belonged to the USA, carried 9 guns of size 16-inch (bore, or inside diameter of the barrel), and weighted (displaced, in nautical terms) 46,000 tons. A typical tuple for Battles is:

```
 ('Hood', 'North Atlantic', 'sunk')
```

List all the pairs of countries that fought each other in battles. List each pair only once, and list them with the country that comes first in alphabetical order first.

Currently, I have this for the implementation, but it is printing out all the matches rather than the correct result.

```
SELECT a.country, b.country 
  FROM ships a, ships b, battles b1, battles b2 
     WHERE a.name=b1.ship and b1.battleName=b2.battleName
       AND a.country>b.country
```

Comment: Surely the course doesn't teach joins this way!?!?

Comment: I cannot +1 @Strawberry's comment enough!

Comment: This bit is odd `a.country>b.country` because it's the only join expression on `ships b` which is not going to work.

Comment: Conrad Frix - that's not a join condition; he's trying to figure out how to eliminate pairings like 'Zambia','Austria','Wollaberg' and only show 'Austria','Zambia','Wollaberg' .

Comment: Countries can be allies, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit joins are preferable.
Try using `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates, and don't forget to `ORDER` them.
Here, we're assuming that only two countries are in each war (they fought each other).

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.country, s2.country
FROM battles b1
JOIN ships s1
ON s1.name = b1.ship
JOIN battles b2
ON b2.battlename = b1.battlename
JOIN ships s2
ON s2.name = b2.ship
WHERE s1.country > s2.country
ORDER BY s1.country, s2.country
```

Comment: +1, and if you want to get fancy, you can also add this to the select line: `, s1.country + ' vs. ' + s2.country`, so it shows up as "USA vs. Ireland" or something.